# Как получить значение из метода?

Tags: node.js, javascript

У меня, оказывается, вообще беда с пониманием контекста в js.
Есть такой код -

```
var fs = require('fs');
var link = 'path';

var cwd = undefined;

fs.realpath(link, function(error, path){
     // как мне получить свойство path
});

console.log(/*здесь?*/);
```

Вопрос в коде, но я хочу попросить рассказать и показать все способы, которыми можно получить желаемое и отдельно пометить ЛУЧШЕЕ.

Comment: Асинхронный метод вы никак синхронным не сделаете (в смысле console.log **всегда** выполнится раньше, чем callback в асинхронных методах).

Comment: У Вас проблема в понимании что асинхронности. Вот буквально сегодня [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEgOzb7EmEM) посмотрел, думаю Вам будет полезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь работать с асинхронным методом, как с синхронным, если это один раз при инициализации приложения, то [fs.realpathSync](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_path_cache).

Comment: @eicto, теперь понимаю почему в доках многие методы имеют дубль с sync. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте засунуть `console.log` в `setTimeout`. Так как `setTimeout` выполнится позже, переменная будет доступна.

Answer (score -1):

Можно заранее создать глобальную переменную, а в методе присвоить этой переменной значение path:

```
var pathGlobal;

fs.realpath(link, function(error, path){
     pathGlobal = path;
     // как мне получить свойство path
});

console.log(pathGlobal);
```

Comment: Видите, у меня свойство cwd есть, так вот я пробовал сделать точно так же, как у Вас, и ничего не выходит. Почему?

Comment: Да потому что на момент вызова `console.log(pathGlobal);` переменная `pathGlobal` равна `undefined`. Путь там появится только после выполнения `fs.realpath ...`, а это будет будет на следующей итерации событийного цикла.